# How many Dothraki are left as of Game of Thrones S8E5?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In episode 3 we see

> The Dothraki getting slaughtered by the undead army.

Keeping that in mind, how many Dothraki are left in Daenerys' army as of the events of Season 8 Episode 5?

Comment: [This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/211912/58193) is extremely related, forgot about it initially, but it might not be a dupe "what is left" versus "How did they survive".

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot i can see the similarities yeah, i'll leave my question here either way to serve as an easier way for people to find an answer

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot isn't the newly edited title a bit spoilery?

Comment: Not really, the answer could be 100%, 0% or anywhere in between it isn't really giving away anything. And anyway it's more accurate, I believe, to what you're asking than what it was changed to before my edit.

Comment: Exactly in one unit of "Plot amount", denoted ℓ P, is the number of Dothraki, that can be observered either dead or alive, in one unit of "Plot time". This number does not stay constant between observation. There is no known number that is inferior or superior to in one unit of "Plot amount".

Comment: My observation is that no matter how few Dothraki you may think Daenerys has, she always has some more. For plot reasons, you can basically assume that she has a Dothraki generator.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Half are gone before the ride down to King's Landing. Watch the below scene [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WfMBItXNTE).

> **Grey Worm:** Half are gone. *Grey Worm removes half of the Unsullied markers.*
>
> **Jon Snow:** The Northmen as well. *Jon Snow removes half of the Northmen markers.*
>
> *Yohn Royce removes half of the Arryn markers.*
>
> *Dothraki soldier removes half of the Dothraki markers.*
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 8 Episode 4, "The Last of the Starks"</sub>

The remaining then split with most riding with Jon but some going on the ships to Dragonstone. As they are ambushed at Dragonstone I think we can safely say at least some die here.

> **Tyrion Lannister:** So if all are in agreement Jon and Ser Davos will ride down the Kingsroad with the Northern troops and the bulk of the remaining Dothraki and Unsullied. A smaller group of us will ride to White Harbor, and sail from there to Dragonstone with our queen and her dragons accompanying us from above.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 8 Episode 4, "The Last of the Starks"</sub>

Then in Season 8 episode 5, "The Bells", the Dothraki enter the city and attack, considering they storm the city at least some may have died and I'm pretty sure the horse Arya uses was a Dothraki one. As such we can say there are still Dothraki left, we see them in the preview for the final episode, but we don't know how many exactly.

[image: Season 8 Episode 6 preview showing Dany looking over her remaining forces]

Comment: It looks a lot like Harry Strickland's horse from the start of the battle (it has the same mop of fluffy white mane over its face), although if it is, it's somehow lost its saddle. I guess it could just be that they used the same horse to portray both Srickland's horse and later a Dothraki horse, hence the lack of saddle.

Comment: @delinear The horses have different coloured snouts so it isn't Harry's.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot the horses have identical snouts, and is definitely Strickland's - https://imgur.com/a/TkMyYv0 (although the leather bridle appears to be different)

Comment: @Joe And Harry's looks like it dies. Though looking again I think there's multiple horses involved. I've seen images of Harry's where it has a completely black snout.

Comment: It's all pretty neat that in episode 4 they say "half is gone," where in episode 3's _Inside the episode_ the creators explicitly say ["What they see is just the end of the Dothraki, essentially."](https://youtu.be/ZJ1yC3yESLQ?t=123) Pretty solid writing, is what that is.

Comment: @JNat Don't know what you mean the writing this season is excellent and they know their own show inside and out! </s>

Comment: @Joe Strickland's horse died. You can see it in the show, and it's also confirmed by the post-episode making of, where they explicitly mention the horse dying. They may have reused the same horse (sure looks like it) but it's not the same in-universe horse.

Comment: As the writers hint at in their interviews - I'm afraid the answer to the question is "Exactly as many are needed in Episode 6".

Comment: @BruceWayne: Honestly, your comment appears to be the best answer.

Comment: The first quote to this answer is... interesting, because any one of those commanders could easily be holding back, deciding in that moment not to risk half their forces in the next engagement.

Comment: Perhaps the soldier did not understand the rules of the table top game they where playing and remove half his markers to mimics others.